# laravel multi update row with input data

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

[View app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWUuw.png)

I made a multi update row with js ... the button function uses put to retrieve the id of each row ...
this success but..
I want to add input form for data that is updated

I don't know what to do

```
<form action="{{ url('UpdateAll') }}" >
  <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="test">
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary delete_all" value="Mass Update">
</form>
```

[code detail](https://pastebin.com/ciWVhn4g)

Comment: Please provide some more information. help others to help you!

Answer (score 0):

I just had a look at your code in the link provided. Is it because your ajax request PUT url is set to :

```
url: $(this).data('url'),
```

But you're not actually setting that URL on your input? eg.

This:

```
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary delete_all" value="Mass Update">
```

Should be:

```
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary delete_all" value="Mass Update" data-url="/your-put-url-here">
```

Comment: Please could you explain what you mean a little more clearly?